# Lightsail amazon - Can't reach port

Tags: port, angular

I have an angular app on a Lightsail server. It seems to run correctly

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y2GO.png)

I created the rule in the network tab on the 4200 port

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VsoK.png)

But I cannot reach it from the outside ...

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow4bZ.png)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.

You have to run ng serve with the sudo and host option .

Then access to your server in http if you didn't set the ssl.

sudo ng serve --host 0.0.0.0